# Click on document but not on a specific div with pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to click anywhere in the document but not in the element with id `overlay_home_page`. How is that possible with pure JavaScript? Thanks

```
document.getElementById("overlay_home_page").addEventListener("click", off);
```

Comment: like `.addEventListener("click", () => { return false; });` ?

Comment: yes but when clicked on document should return true

Answer (score 3):

For this `div` set the [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to `none` in css file. When set to `none` the element is never the target of mouse events.

```
#overlay_home_page{
 pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: If pointer events are needed within this div, I believe this will also disable those as well.

Comment: I click outside of the div with id `#overlay_home_page` and returns false

Answer (score 2):

Listen for clicks on the whole window.
When the click event is fired, check whether or not your div [contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) any of the event's target:

```
window.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay_home_page');
  if (!overlay.contains(event.target)){
    // do something
  }
});
```